# condicional en python me arroja siempre falso

Tags: python, lista

Tengo esta función en python, la cual de una lista en la que hay int y str, me devuelve otra lista pero con solo los int.

El problema es que en el If , siempre me arroja falso, quisiera que me ayudarán a saber porque siempre me da falso, así lo intente con puros int dentro de la lista. Saludos

```
def filter_list(l):
a=[]
for i in range(0,len(l),1):
    if type(l[i])=="<class 'int'>":             <--aqui
        a.append(l[i])
    else:
        continue
return a
```

Comment: Lo que te devuelve `type` no es un string. Si deseas saber si una variable es de un tipo de dato solo basta con hacer `if type(l[i]) == int:` o con `if isinstance(l[i], int): `

Comment: @Christian hay que tener en cuenta que isinstance(value, type) devuelve true para instancias de clases derivadas de type. Por ejemplo isinstance(subclasedeint(1), int) devuelve true.

Comment: @DanteS. Los comentarios me quedan cortos :)

Comment: @Christian ya veo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amén del comentario de Christian:

> Lo que te devuelve type no es un string. Si deseas saber si una
> variable es de un tipo de dato solo basta con hacer if type(l[i]) ==
> int: o con if isinstance(l[i], int):

hay varias mejores que hacer al código.

En primera instancia, la iteración. Si quieres revisar los elementos de una lista, los puedes obtener directamente, sin necesidad de pasar por los indices, con un `for elemento in l:`

```
def filter_list(l):
    a=[]
    for elemento in l:
        if type(elemento) == int:
            a.append(elemento)
    return a
```

El `else: continue` es innecesario, pues si el `if` no se cumple, sólo queda pasar al siguiente elemento, cosa que igual ocurrirá naturalmente.

Se puede mejorar más usando comprensión de listas:

```
def filter_list(l):
    return [elemento for elemento in l if type(elemento) == int]
```

que es una manera más compacta de significar lo mismo.

La expresión

```
[elemento for elemento in l]
```

retorna una nueva lista con los mismos elementos que `l`, pero podemos agregar un `if type(elemento) == int` que revise cada elemento y diga si debe ser incluido o no en la nueva lista, lo que nos da la expresión final.

Answer (score 0):

La función `filter` hace precisamente eso, extraer elementos de un `iterable` cuando se cumple una condición:

```
list(filter(lambda x: type(x) == int, l))
```